onMessage method in websokcet listener is not invoked
This is the front end
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Button connectBtn=findViewById(R.id.connectBtn);
        connectBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
                Request request = new Request.Builder().url("ws://localhost:8080/ws").build();
                WebSocketListener listener=new WebSocketListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClosed(@NonNull WebSocket webSocket, int code, @NonNull String reason) {
                        super.onClosed(webSocket, code, reason);
                        output("Closed: "+reason);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onClosing(@NonNull WebSocket webSocket, int code, @NonNull String reason) {
                        super.onClosing(webSocket, code, reason);
                        output("Closing: "+reason);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull WebSocket webSocket, @NonNull Throwable t, @Nullable Response response) {
                        super.onFailure(webSocket, t, response);
                        output("Failed: "+ t);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onMessage(@NonNull WebSocket webSocket, @NonNull String text) {
                        super.onMessage(webSocket, text);
                        output("Received: "+text);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onMessage(@NonNull WebSocket webSocket, @NonNull ByteString bytes) {
                        super.onMessage(webSocket, bytes);
                        output("Received bytes: "+bytes.hex());
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onOpen(@NonNull WebSocket webSocket, @NonNull Response response) {
                        super.onOpen(webSocket, response);
                        Message message=new Message("Hello");
                        Gson gson=new Gson();
                        String jsonMessage=gson.toJson(message);
                        output("connected: "+response);
                        webSocket.send("SUBSCRIBE\n" +
                                "destination:/topic/public\n" +
                                "id:sub-01\n" +
                                "\n" +
                                "\0");

                        webSocket.send("SEND\n" +
                                "destination:/app/message\n" +
                                "Content-Type: application/json\n"+
                                "\n" +
                                jsonMessage +
                                "\0");
                    }
                };
                WebSocket webSocket= client.newWebSocket(request,listener);
            }
        });
    }
    public void output(String s){
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                System.out.println(s);
            }
        });
    }
}

This is the backend
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class WebSocketConfig implements WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {
    @Override
    public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
        registry.addEndpoint("/ws");
    }

    @Override
    public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry registry) {
        registry.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app");
        registry.enableSimpleBroker("/topic");
    }
}
@Controller
public class ChatController {
    @MessageMapping("/message")
    @SendTo("/topic/public")
    public Message sendMessage(Message message){
        System.out.println(message);
        return message;
    }
}

I am trying to build a simple chat app on android using spring boot on backend and okhttp on android.
I can successfully connect to the websocket also the message hello is sent to the backend as it gets printed on console. The sendMessage method on backend returns Message. Messages are received in onMessage method but for some reason the onMessage method is not invoked. I don't know how to fix this problem.
I am new on websocket for this I am lost at this point.

Kindly provide the clear information means what is the issue you are getting? You told Messages are received in onMessage method but for some reason the onMessage method is not invoked.

After i send message to /app/message on backend i can see that the message is send to this endpoint on backend in sendMessage function but no response sent on the client side

do you mean when you send message at that time you also want to see response in onMessage() method in WebSocketListener at front-end side ?
